# Titanium Alloy compile failed without error message

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

When i try to build with titanium studio, i got error message :

```
[ERROR] :  
[ERROR] :  Alloy compiler failed
```

Without another error message, just a blank error message and build is not done.
How can i check which file has an issue ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compiler fails it is usually always a typo somewhere in your code. In Studio, check for a little red attention mark next to the filename of the files in your project folder.

Comment: FWIW, I ran into this and couldn't find a typo anywhere in my code (which is a simple demo project). I'm not using an IDE, just a text editor and the command line, so I was unable to look for the red attention marks. The issue for me ended up being that I used a dash/hyphen in an ID.